# CodenameOne issue handling mouse events on iOS 12 and 13 in BrowserComponent

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, ios-simulator, codenameone, wkwebview

I am testing my CodenameOne app on the iOS simulator.

It is good practice to test on the main iOS versions.

My app has a BrowserComponent as main interface, where a list of Frames is displayed.

Text inside the frames is not selectable. This is ensured by means of

```
iframe.style.pointerEvents="none";
```

Mouse events are managed to address single press and long press. It is accomplished by means of detecting the events

```
"touchstart"
```

and

```
"touchend"
```

and computing the time interval. Javascript callbacks are used.

(also "touchmove" is detected to cancel some events so just "pure" touches are detected)

This works fine in the CN1 simulator, Android devices, and

on iOS simulator with iOS 10, iOS 11, iOS 14

but

it does not work on

iOS 12. iOS 13

What happens is that the mouse events are consumed by the BrowserComponent in such a way that the selection handles appear and the text is selectable.

I had to reinvent the wheel because I am using this CN1 cross-platform tool.

There is also an opened issue:

```
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3378
```

it is why I am not using "mousedown" and "mouseup" events. But it is not bad to use "touch" events on mobile devices.

(Furthermore I have to say that those "touch" events are useful also in the SwiftUI version, that uses WKWebView, to manage the mouse events as my app needs. It is because I have to use the same Javascript code in both apps.
But there is not the "selection handles appearing" issue with WKWebView. It is only tested on iOS 14, so I cannot say more about that.)

Now it does not work on iOS 12, 13.

I have a SwiftUI version of my app for iOS 14. So the CN1 version was mainly intended for older versions. If iOS 12 and 13 are "gone", it is not useful to publish it just for iOS 9,10,11, I think.

What's wrong with iOS 12, 13 with CN1? Has it special issues with some major changes in those OS versions that were not addressed?

If it is fault of the flaky BrowserComponent on the iOS simulator, it also has to be considered that the mouse events handling works on iOS 14, 11, 10.

So will it be flaky also on the real devices?

How to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. I reviewed the code and I don't see anywhere that should impact that as we don't do anything related to selection in WKWebView. I also Googled similar problems and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: If you can, try to test it on the actual device. It might behave differently comparing to simulator.